# How to find a node's predecessor in a BST with each node having 3 attributes--succ,left and right?

Tags: algorithm, clrs

A problem from CLRS ,3ed.

> 12.3-5
>   Suppose that instead of each node x keeping the attribute x.p, pointing to x’s parent, it keeps x.succ, pointing to x’s successor. Give pseudocode for SEARCH,INSERT, and DELETE on a binary search tree T using this representation. These procedures should operate in time O(h), where h is the height of the tree T . (Hint:You may wish to implement a subroutine that returns the parent of a node.)

I know how to implement a subroutine that returns the parent of a node in O(h) time.

To find the parent of node `x`, we should find the maximum key `M` in the subtree rooted at `x` first. Then, we go downward to the right from `M.succ.left`. When we reach `x`, the node we encounter before `x` is `x`'s parent.

See the code.

```
typedef struct TREE{
  struct TREE* left,right,succ;
}*BST;

PARENT(BST x)
{
  if(x==root) return NULL;
  BST max=TREE_MAXIMUM(x);
  BST parent=max->succ,t;
  if(parent) t=parent->left;
  else t=root;
  while(t!=x){parent=t;t=t->right;}
  return parent;
}
```

When `DELETE` `x`, the succ of `x`'s predecessor should be modified to point to `x.succ`, no longer `x`. So now comes the problem--how to find the predecessor of `x` in O(h) time?

When the left subtree of `x` is nonempty, it's the rightmost node in `x`'s left subtree. However, when the left subtree of `x` is empty, the predecessor is `x`'s ancestor, to find which calls O(h) times of `PARENT`. Does that needs O(h*h) time? Or should we search downward from the root?

Notice that the operation `INSERT`, also needs to find a node's predecessor.

**There comes a question--what if all the keys share the same value? Then we cannot find `x`'s predecessor using comparison, for the key `a`, which equals to key `x`, may appears in `x`'s left subtree or right subtree.**

Comment: why would you need to call the `parent` subroutine O(h) times? why isn't once sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

In case the left subtree of `x` is empty, the predecessor of `x` is not just its ancestor, it's the direct parent of `x`. So you only need a single call to the `parent` subroutine, making the over all runtime `O(h)+O(h)=O(h)`.

**P.S**
Even if it wasn't the direct parent, you still don't have to call `parent` repeatedly to get all ancestors, you can just start searching for `x` from the root of the tree as you normally would, saving all of the nodes along the path to `x` in a single traversal of length `O(h)`. All of the nodes you pass through when searching for `x`, and only those nodes, are by definition the ancestors of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

If keys are discrete, the predecessor of x has key that is <= key(x)-1 right? And if you search the tree for key(x)-1 what happens? Don't you necessarily run into pred(x) during that traverse? You'd have to double-check me on that. And of course non-discrete keys (e.g. floating point) could be problematic (as to -1).

Answer (score 0):

Note : O(h) is only possible if the root is directly available.(which should be the case)

Changing your data structure a bit.

```
typedef struct TREE{
 int key;
 struct TREE* left,right,succ;
}*BST;
```

If the left sub-tree is non-empty we use TREE_MAXIMUM, otherwise we search for x in the BST starting the search from root and maintain(in variable goal) the last(i.e latest) node encountered with a right child. At the end of the search, goal is the predecessor.

Predecessor function

```
 BST PRE(BST x)
    {
      if(x->left!=NULL)
          return TREE_MAXIMUM(x->left);
      if(x== root)
          return NULL;
      BST goal = NULL, y = root;
      while(1)
      {
        if(x->key <= y->key)
            y=y->left;
        else
        {
            goal=y;
            y=y->right;
        }
        if(x==y)
        {
            return goal;
        }
      }      
    }
```